# General help call for cloth simulation

Tags: cloth-simulation

OK, I´ve tinkering with the cloth simulation for about a month and I´m clueless. I´m trying to do a quite basic tracksuit.

Link to the blend file:

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5d59d89856339bbc12c3ba626af25eef20210808180955/495332f8ff05fe465ba3e37beadc369520210808181012/044b5e

[image: model]

I´ve tried to model it in two separate pieces (jacket and trousers) and later just in one mesh, made the animation slower, tried different character scales, rised the qquality steps, etc... but the best I´ve managed to get is a glitchy animation.

[image: glitch]

In some cases, the cloth just rips apart and the character ends walking half nude, something that made me laugh the first time that happened but now makes me cry.

[image: total failure]

So, what am I doing wrong? Maybe it´s that I need to buy a better machine to increase the quality steps (I think the max I´ve tried is around 25, but the result was not very good either and the CPU was on fire).  Maybe it´s just that I´m asking too much from Blender´s cloth simulation and I should pay for Marvelous Designer or something like that?

Comment: It’s possible that the cloth is too tight for the margin you have it set for.

Comment: Running an animation with a cloth simulation on top is a challenging and very calculation-intensive task. Your mesh for the cloth is very simple and low-poly, not ideal for animation because it lacks geometry at the elbows and knees for example. To compensate for this, you added more geometry with help of the *Subdivision Surface* modifier. But this introduces more geometry as you need and more problems (wobble effect) and performance issues. Sometimes less is more.

Comment: I would start with a shirt created from the body mesh & keep it low-poly. Then make a high-poly version (*Multires* modifier), bake a normal map, and apply the shape of the high-poly to the low poly to get some wrinkles. Then run a cloth sim with the low poly with the animation. Alternatively, you could try to use the low-poly mesh as a proxy for the high-poly mesh (*Surface Deform* modifier)

Comment: By the way, have you baked the simulation data? I've done that (took a long while), and the cloth didn't crawl up. But the shirt intersects the pants at the belly. And there is this wobble effect. It looks a bit weird. Your cloth settings are very... - experimental. 1250 stiffness!

Comment: OK, thanks for the info, I´ll try that. Jeez, it seems that cloth simulation is harder than those "towel and ball" tutorials pretend.

I know that some parameters are weird, but many tutorials say that it´s better to do the simulation in an upscaled model, so the stiffness and so on need to grow accordingly.